# Focus-Visible not working when hover over the expanding button in tailwindcss

Tags: hover, tailwind-css

In here there is a **react Component** created using the **tailwindCss and reactTypescript**.
component is **AnimatingTabs.tsx** here below [image]

here i use the **focus-visible** in tailwind to show when focus using the tab in windows key. but there is two scenarios
[image]

1- in **HorizontalTab** focusVisble Working
[image]
[image]

2- in **verticalTab** focusVisible only for the button not for the hovered area

[image]

so in code wise we wraping in motion.nav underneath there is div have the button children inside it have tabLabel and tabIcon children.

```
   <div
          ref={tabRef as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>}
          className={clsx('flex', {
            'py-px': orientation === 'vertical',
            [clsx({
              'flex-1': fullWidth === 'stretch-active' && isActive,
              flex: fullWidth === 'space-between' || fullWidth === 'none',
            })]: orientation === 'horizontal',
            [clsx('flex', {
              'flex flex-1 items-center': fullWidth === 'space-between',
              'flex-1': fullWidth === 'stretch-active' && isActive,
            })]: orientation === 'vertical',
            'cursor-not-allowed': disabled,
          })}
        >
          <AnimatePresence>
            <motion.button
              tabIndex={isHovered ? -1 : 0}
              onClick={handleTabClick}
              disabled={disabled}
              className={clsx(
                classNames?.wrapper,
                'relative flex items-center rounded-full',
                {
                  [clsx('focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-1', {
                    'focus-visible:hover:ring-primary-400 focus-visible:hover:ring-opacity-50 focus-visible:hover:ring-offset-primary-200':
                      theme === 'primary',
                    'focus-visible:ring-secondary-400 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50 focus-visible:ring-offset-secondary-200':
                      theme === 'secondary',
                    'focus-visible:ring-gray-400 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50 focus-visible:ring-offset-gray-200':
                      theme === 'dark',
                    'focus-visible:ring-gray-300 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50 focus-visible:ring-offset-gray-100':
                      theme === 'light',
                    'focus-visible:ring-success-400 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50 focus-visible:ring-offset-success-200':
                      theme === 'success',
                    'focus-visible:ring-warning-400 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50 focus-visible:ring-offset-warning-200':
                      theme === 'warning',
                    'focus-visible:ring-danger-400 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50 focus-visible:ring-offset-danger-200':
                      theme === 'danger',
                  })]: orientation === 'horizontal' || 'vertical',
                },
                {
                  [clsx({
                    'bg-primary-100': theme === 'primary',
                    'bg-secondary-100': theme === 'secondary',
                    'bg-gray-100': theme === 'light',
                    'bg-gray-300': theme === 'dark',
                    'bg-success-100': theme === 'success',
                    'bg-warning-100': theme === 'warning',
                    'bg-danger-100': theme === 'danger',
                  })]: orientation === 'horizontal' && isActive,
                }
              )}
              onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
              animate={
                orientation === 'horizontal' && isActive
                  ? 'active'
                  : orientation === 'horizontal' && !isActive
                  ? 'inactive'
                  : false
              }
              variants={{
                inactive: {
                  width: iconWidthPadding,
                },
                active: {
                  width: verticalLabelWidth,
                  flex: fullWidth === 'stretch-active' ? 1 : 0,
                },
              }}
              initial={false}
            >
              <TabIcon isActive={isActive} disabled={disabled} icon={icon} />
              <TabLabel
                isActive={isActive}
                tabIndex={tabIndex}
                isHovered={isHovered}
                maxLabelWidth={verticalLabelWidth}
                iconWidth={iconWidthPadding}
              >
                {label}
              </TabLabel>
            </motion.button>
          </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
```

so what want is when hoverOver the button in vertical i need the focus-visible will cover the all.

I need how we can focus-Visible in tailwind css when hover over the element which change dynamically.